# Decoding a nested array using Codable structs in Swift 4 is only working with an array size of 1

Tags: arrays, json, swift4, codable, decodable

I have a JSON payload that is formatted like this:

```
{
    items: [
       {
          id: 1,
          anotherKey: anotherValue
       },
       {
          id: 2,
          anotherKey: anotherValue
       }
    ]
}
```

This is the code I am using to decode the payload:

```
   struct Suggestions : Codable {
        let items: [EmployeeDTO]
    }

    if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Suggestions.self, from: response.data!) {
        print("decoding success, json is \(json)")
    }
    else {
        print("failed")
    }
```

My EmployeeDTO is defined in an external file as a Codeable struct as well. The problem I am running into is the decoding only works if my array only has 1 result. In other words, an array of just 1 single EmployeeDTO object. As soon as I have an array of 2 or more objects, the decoding fails and it goes straight to the else. Any ideas on why this happens? I am stumped. This is the document I have been using as a guide with parsing nested objects with arrays: http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/

Comment: Your code works fine: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59920827cb3d25200b153425 (Your JSON's keys must be enclosed in double quotes)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I copied the last 2 lines that you used and realized my code was silently failing because I had try? rather than try!. Turns out one of the attributes in my EmployeeDTO object should have been an Optional and it was blowing up because it saw a null value. It just so happens that the payload that came back with just 1 item happened to have values for all attributes which is why it appeared to be working.